# How to constraintvalues in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, constraints

`tsc` version: 3.9.6

I want to constrain the value of `getColDict()`.

In my interface `ColDict<T>`, key is any string, value must be `T`, in my case `T` is type `Column`.

My code is here:

```
interface ColDict<T> {
  [i: string]: T;
}

function getColDict<T>(): ColDict<T> {
  return {
    id: { title: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id' },  // **constraint here**
    name: { title: 'NAME', dataIndex: 'name' },  // **constraint here**
    xxx: { title: 'YYY', dataIndex: 'zzz' },  // **constraint here**
  };
}

// =====================================

export type Column = {
  title: string;
  dataIndex: string;
  width: number;
};

const colDict = getColDict<Column>();

const columns: Column[] = [
  { ...colDict.id, width: 80 },
  { ...colDict.name, width: 80 },
  { ...colDict.xxx, width: 80 },
];

console.log('columns: ', columns);
```

I get the error:

```
id: { title: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id' },
~~

Type '{ title: string; dataIndex: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ title: string; dataIndex: string; }'.ts(2322)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you are trying to do. There are a few issues. Firstly, `getColDict()` shouldn't be generic because nothing in the implementation depends on the generic parameter. You don't enforce constraints that way. Instead you should explicitly define the column interface that `getColDict()` generates and then TS will give you an error if you try to assign the return value to an object of a different type. It would look like this:

```
interface ColDict<T> {
  [i: string]: T;
}

interface ColumnType {
  title: string
  dataIndex: string
}

function getColDict(): ColDict<ColumnType> {
  return {
    id: { title: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id' },  // **constraint here**
    name: { title: 'NAME', dataIndex: 'name' },  // **constraint here**
    xxx: { title: 'YYY', dataIndex: 'zzz' },  // **constraint here**
  };
}

// =====================================

export type Column = {
  title: string;
  dataIndex: string;
  width: number;
};

const colDict: ColDict<Column> = getColDict(); // Error, Property 'width' is missing in type 'ColumnType' but required in type 'Column'.
```

Comment: I want pass the grenric `Column` to `ColDict<T>` , so I can constraints the value of  `getColDict()`. 
If the `getColDict()` don't konw the shape of data, how can I constraints the results of `getColDict()`?

Comment: @Witee if you mean that you want the error to be reported in `getColDict` then the answer is that TS won't do that. There is no error in that function until the point where you call the method so that is always the point where TS will report a type mismatch.

Comment: @Witee This solution does enforce the constraint that you are asking for, it just reports the error on the assignment line instead of inside `getColDict`

Comment: My fault.
How can I constraint the result of `getColDict()` with generic `T` in other ways?

Comment: @Witee This is the only way. Generics in typescript are not like templates in C++. The complier doesn't generate multiple implementations of the function so it can't give you type errors specific to one of those implementations. There is only one function. The type error can only happen on the line where you explicitly define the concrete constraint (i.e. the line where you introduce `Column`).

Comment: Oh, so it is. Thanks a lot. I'll go and read more documents.